# FontAwesome inherits parent font-size causing bad rednering

Tags: font-awesome

Each FontAwesome icon is set up to inherit font-size of its parent. However, the font is best rendered at specific sizes and if the parent has anything different than `font-size: 14px;` it will effect the icon quality. My question is, why use CSS like this

```
.fa {font-size: none;}
.fa-lg {font-size: 1.33333333em;}
.fa-2x {font-size: 2em;}
.fa-3x {font-size: 3em;}
.fa-4x {font-size: 4em;}
.fa-5x {font-size: 5em;}
```

without knowing what's the parent font-size and therefore risk having badly rendered icons and not have this

```
.fa {font-size: 14px;}
.fa-lg {font-size: 19px;}
.fa-2x {font-size: 28px;}
.fa-3x {font-size: 42px;}
.fa-4x {font-size: 56px;}
.fa-5x {font-size: 70px;}
```

where we make sure that each icon has the best possible quality.

Comment: It's not so much of a problem with what unit to use, but why FontAwesome is "shipped" with font-size in ems requiring additional configuration, when they could be set in pixels. Is there an actual idea behind it? Is it supposed to make something easier?

Answer (score 0):

So, you would like to know why font-awesome is using 'em' units over 'px'. Is that right?

Reason:

Lets say you have a heading text (`<h1>`) of size 30px. And a paragraph (`<p>`) text of 14px. Both has icons.

So, if the font-awesome icons is in fixed size like 14px, it will render properly for body text. But it will look small in heading tags, as icon is in 14px and heading text is in 30px.

If we use relative size, then we can use parent's font size, so the icon and text wont be in different sizes.

Also, if they have fixed size, and if it doesn't match with your website's font size, you need to manually reset its font size every time. Some people use '13px' as their base font size and some will have '15px'.

We don't know what would be the users font size for any particular element, and that's why we are using `em` and `rem` units.

If I am not clear, sorry :(

Thanks!

Comment: Question in answer is discouraged. If you need more information, add comment. If you do not have enough reputation to comment, explore more and more and earn reputation then comment. Thanks!